# How does this #define work in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, variadic-functions

I am new to iOS and am trying to tackle learning Swift (and a bit of Objective C) by converting a library I found to the former. So far I'm doing alright, but am having trouble understanding one part; how this `#define` is supposed to work:

```
#define RunSafeBlock(block, ...) block ? block(__VA_ARGS__) : nil
```

Here it is with more context:

```
#import <AFNetworking.h>

// How would I write this in Swift?
#define RunSafeBlock(block, ...) block ? block(__VA_ARGS__) : nil

@interface Client ()
@end

@implementation Client
- (void)requestWithBodyBlock:(void (^)(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData))bodyBlock  completion:(ClientRequestCompletion)completion {
    [self validateAccessToken:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // What does RunSafeBlock do?
            RunSafeBlock(completion, nil, error);
            return;
        }

        // ...
    }];
}
@end
```

The `AFNetworking` parts are not really relevant, but in this example we're performing a request and validating an access token. If `validateAccessToken` returns an error, we pass everything to `RunSafeBlock` and exit out. Here we are in Swift:

```
import AFNetworking

// #define RunSafeBlock(block, ...) block ? block(__VA_ARGS__) : nil

class Client {
    func requestWithBodyBlock(bodyBlock: (formData: AFMultipartFormData) -> Void, completion: ClientRequestCompletion) {
        self.validateAccessToken({(error: NSError) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                // RunSafeBlock(completion, nil, error)
                return
            }

            // ...
        })
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate some guidance. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This macro is doing a null-check.

In Swift, unless you declare a variable as Optional, it cannot be null, so you do not have to do this check in Swift (and if it was Optional, you'd use optional unwrapping).

So just go ahead and call the `completion`.

(It seems the same reasoning would also apply to `error`. Don't you get a compile error there?)

(Also consider using the [Swift version of AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!